# CrashReporter -- what are '+' symbols?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

```
Binary Images:
   0x10225d000 -        0x102261fff  com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent (1.0 - 1) <9765C1E9-AB12-3755-B5DE-8CC9D53D3C22> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AmbientDisplay.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent
   0x10226f000 -        0x102276fff +libwep (1) <83C200B0-EE65-3488-B3E1-32185CFA50BC> /usr/local/lib/libwep
   0x1024d7000 -        0x10250eff7 +libwep_proxy.dylib (1) <D4698BD4-DC26-35A8-808D-4D3643C59F26> /usr/local/lib/libwep_proxy.dylib
0x7fff63250000 -     0x7fff63287007  dyld (360.19) <9D05FDF4-65CE-3B53-86D4-ABE1A5BF35F3> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I am wondering what these '+' mean. Is it possible that libwep is trying to inject itself in com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent?

libwep is shipped with Websense AP-Endpoint.

Full crash+panic:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ee339cc665cdc8583bea

Comment: could it be something like this?        DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
              This  is  a colon separated list of dynamic libraries to load before the ones specified in the
              program.  This lets you test new modules of existing dynamic shared libraries that are used in
              flat-namespace images by loading a temporary dynamic shared library with just the new modules.
              Note that this has no effect on images built a two-level  namespace  images  using  a  dynamic
              shared library unless DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE is also used.